# Haskell: parallel do versus list comprehension

Tags: haskell, parallel-processing

To make a list comprehension run in parallel, it's easy to tack on `using parList rdeepseq`, but what if the list comprehension is expressed using `do` notation?

For example, this bit of code runs just fine in parallel.

```
    entry n = [ (rowSet,finalEV rowSet,rrDone rowSet,oneRRLeft rowSet,twoRRLeft rowSet) | rowSet <- getChoiceList 13 n] `using` parList rdeepseq
      where
          prevFinal = getFinalEVNEW $ entry (n-1)
          
          rrDone rowSet = (getRRDoneNEW prevFinal rowSet)
          
          doneStripped rowSet = map (\(v,_,ev) -> (v,ev)) (rrDone rowSet)
          oneRRLeft rowSet = getRRChoicesNEW (doneStripped rowSet)
          
          oneRRStripped rowSet = map (\(v,_,ev) -> (v,ev)) (oneRRLeft rowSet)
          twoRRLeft rowSet = getRRChoicesNEW (oneRRStripped rowSet)
          
          twoRRStripped rowSet = map (\(v,_,ev) -> (v,ev)) (twoRRLeft rowSet)
          finalEV rowSet = weightedEV theProbs (twoRRStripped rowSet)
```

But it's easier to read when expressed with `do` notation. The part above, expressed in do form, and with the broader context becomes:

```
monster :: [[([Bool],Double,[([Int],Int,Double)],[([Int],[Bool],Double)],[([Int],[Bool],Double)])]]

monster = [ entry i | i <- [0..13] ]
  where
    entry 0 = [(replicate 13 False,0,[],[],[])]
    
    entry n = go ( getFinalEVNEW ( entry (n-1) ) )
      where
        go prevFinal = do 
          
          rowSet <- (getChoiceList 13 n )
          
          let rrDone = (getRRDoneNEW prevFinal rowSet)
          let doneStripped = map (\(v,_,ev) -> (v,ev)) rrDone
          let oneRRLeft = getRRChoicesNEW doneStripped
          
          let oneRRStripped = map (\(v,_,ev) -> (v,ev)) oneRRLeft
          let twoRRLeft = getRRChoicesNEW oneRRStripped
          
          let twoRRStripped = map (\(v,_,ev) -> (v,ev)) twoRRLeft
          let finalEV = weightedEV theProbs twoRRStripped
          
          return (rowSet,finalEV,rrDone,oneRRLeft,twoRRLeft)
```

But it's unclear how to make the do form run in parallel.

Is there a straightforward way to transform a parallel list comprehension to an equivalent do form?

EDIT: The "do version" was expanded a bit for context.

A related issue is the fact the algorithm is recursive, and any attempt to parallelize `entry n` should wait until `entry (n-1)` is in normal form. Right?

This is a calculation for a solution to a game similar to Yahtzee. It's a "let's learn Haskell" exercise.

Comment: you can use `let ... in ...` instead of `where` clause

Comment: Sorry, why would it be any different? Just tack on the exact same `using` clause. What am I missing?

Comment: I edited the original question to give a bit more context. Maybe the answer is as obvious as you say. I'm a relative novice at Haskell.

Comment: Okay, but `entry` in the first code block does not correspond to `entry` in the second code block. Rather, it's `entry` in the first block and `go` in the second block. Perhaps this is what is confusing you -- perhaps you're trying to envision how to attach the `using` clause to the wrong thing.

Comment: The right thing to do in the go/do version seems to be making each time trough the `do...return` (each `rowSet`) spark a new thread. But how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The straightforward translation of the code you say works looks like this:

```
entry n = go ( getFinalEVNew ( entry (n-1) ) ) `using` parList rdeepseq
```

If you insist on attaching the `using` clause to the `do` block, you can either use parentheses:

```
go prevFinal = (do
  ...
  ) `using` parList rdeepseq
```

or use an indentation level between that of the `where` block and the `do` block:

```
go prevFinal = do
  ...
 `using` parList rdeepseq
```

or apply `using` in prefix:

```
go prevFinal = (`using` parList rdeepseq) $ do
  ...
```

Comment: @RandallFairman Okay. Can you post a complete, minimized reproducing example, showing that the comprehension version parallelizes but the `do` version does not? They really should behave the same.

Comment: Yes, I tried several of these approaches, and they all did the same thing. They compile and run, but don't use more than one core. Let me clean things up (and eat and plow my driveway!) and post on github. It's too much for this forum.

Comment: See https://github.com/rsfairman/yah. I can provide more background, but it probably makes sense to take this elsewhere.

Comment: @RandallFairman Um... I'm not going to sit and look through 1500 lines of code in my off time. The people who are willing to help you are likely to expect you to do some minimization work (certainly I do). e.g. start by replacing the bits you expect to be computationally intensive with `unsafePerformIO (threadDelay 100000 >> pure defaultValue)` or whatever.

Comment: Understood. You confirmed that I'm on the right track anyway. My guess is that it's probably some subtlety about lazy evaluation. Thanks,